# pass argumant in url without clean other argumant use js

Tags: javascript

i use Paginator django and when i click on pages button. url changes to this : `/admin/orders/?page=2`
now i want to set *status* in url arguments like this :
`/admin/orders/?status=1`.
it works!
but in this case when i change page , *status* parameter is cleaned!
i want to set both of parameter in url like this :
`/admin/orders/?status=1&page=2`
how can i solve this problem with js and get a clean url like above?
this my idea but doesn't work :

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#status-filter").click(function(){
              
               var s = $("#status-value").val();
               if(window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1)
                    window.location.href = window.location.href+"&status="+s;
                else
                    window.location.href = window.location.href+"?status="+s;
           })
        });
```

Comment: sry
i edited that and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it!
i should this code :

```
function getParameter(name,href){
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( href );
    if( results == null )
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
function setUrlParameter(name,value){
    var url = window.location;
    var href = url.href;
    var search = url.search;
    var val = getParameter(name,href);
    if(val != ''){
        var param = name+'='+val;
        var new_param = name+'='+value;
        var newUrl = href.replace(param,new_param);
        window.history.pushState("string", "Title", newUrl);
        return false;
     }
     else if(search == ''){
        var param = '?'+name+'='+value;
        var newUrl = href+param;
        window.history.pushState("string", "Title", newUrl);
        return false;
     }
     else if(search != ''){
        var param = '&'+name+'='+value;
        var newUrl = href+param;
        window.history.pushState("string", "Title", newUrl);
        return false;
     }
}
    console.log(setUrlParameter("status","1"));
```